# Select/Unselect all checkboxes on a page on button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

It's possibly duplicate post, please pardon me.
I am using following code to achieve above;

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#uncheckAll').click(function () {
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        });
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        });
    });

 <div class="portlet-body form">
                        @{
                            var htmlListInfo = new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 4, new { @class = "table table-condensed table-light" });
                        }
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Jobs", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <div class="form-body" id="teamRoles">
                                @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.EmployeeTeamRoles,
                                    model => model.AvailableTeamRoles,
                                    entity => entity.Id,
                                    entity => entity.TeamRoleName,
                                    model => model.SelectedTeamRoles,
                                    htmlListInfo)
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions row-fluid">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-circle green-meadow" id="checkAll" type="button"> Check All</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-circle red-sunglo" id="uncheckAll" type="button"> Uncheck All</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-small red-sunglo" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Load Jobs</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
```

It seems fine, but I don't know what am I missing here, can anybody point out my mistake,thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is inside dom ready handeler

Comment: @Learner Add **complete** code

Comment: why negative ?? @Tushar I have posted complete code.

Comment: I think you have to use a particular class for all check boxes instead of using $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);

Comment: because i have a doubt in $(':checkbox'), usually we access any element via id,class or input type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I have worked out the solution; I had to explicitly add css class to the span in which the checkbox is wrapped, as below;

```
 $('#uncheckAll').click(function () {
                $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                $('span').removeClass('checked');
            });
            $("#checkAll").click(function () {
                $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
                $('span').addClass('checked');
            });
```